# Ionic 3x: unit testing, mock for default controllers

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm writing an Ionic app and make test for code inner. I've got an [example](https://github.com/lathonez/clicker) and it's very helpful. But I'm using other stuff like Geolocation or [Loading Controller](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/loading/LoadingController/) for my features and I don't know how should I mock them. For example I provide in `.spec.ts`

`{ provide: LoadingController, useClass: LoadMock }`

but I don't know what should I provide (which type and data). Error logs are not meaningful especially. What I should provide here for Loading Controller for example. It has methods: create, present and dismiss.

```
export class LoadMock {

    public create(): type??? {
        return what???
    }

    public present(): type??? {
        return what???
    }

    public dismiss(): type??? {
        return what???
    }
}
```

Comment: **what** depends on **how** it's used in tested unit. The answers are as good as the question is.

Comment: @estus where can I watch what should I pass and return?

Comment: Where you use LoadingController.

Comment: im using this: https://github.com/stonelasley/ionic-mocks

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on how you are using those components in your code. For example, if you have something like this

```
let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
  content: 'Please wait...'
});

loading.present();

this.getData().then(data => {
  // Do something
  loading.dismiss();
});
```

`present()` and `dismiss()` don't need to return anything since the return values are disregarded. `create()` should return something with functions `present()` and `dismiss()`.

So a mocked `LoadingController` might look something like this

```
export class LoadingMock {

  public create(): any {
    return new LoadingMock;
  }

  public dismiss(): any {}

  public present(): any {}
}
```